# Is there an API to Extract Billing/Payment data from G-Suite Basics?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

[Payment Plan Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLVDJ.png)

This is a dashboard for payment plan details for G-Suite Basic subscription. Is there a Google API to extract the payment details?

Comment: The [Reseller API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest) can help if you're a registered reseller managing several domains, but there's no way to extract this data as an end customer.

Comment: As @mary mentioned you can request this info on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/subscriptions/get. Can you please confirm this is the API expected?